# Calculate overlapping durations in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is making my head hurt! :P

I have an `assignments` table, and I'd like to calculate a member's duration based on their assignments. In its simplified form, this would be relatively straight forward.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id    | member_id | unit_id   | start_date    | end_date  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 2     | 23        | 2013-01-01    | 2013-02-01    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2 | 2     | 25        | 2013-02-01    | 2013-03-01    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3 | 2     | 27        | 2013-03-01    | NULL      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This would just be a matter of doing a `SUM()` of the `DATEDIFF()` on `start_date` and `end_date`. The issue is that members have the potential to have concurrent assignments.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id    | member_id | unit_id   | start_date    | end_date  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 2     | 23        | 2013-01-01    | 2013-02-01    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2 | 2     | 25        | 2013-02-01    | 2013-03-01    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3 | 2     | 30        | 2013-02-15    | 2013-03-01    |*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4 | 2     | 27        | 2013-03-01    | NULL      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I have to somehow realize that #3 occurred during the same time as #2, so I shouldn't add it to the `SUM()`.

Going further, what if the member has gaps in their duration?

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id    | member_id | unit_id   | start_date    | end_date  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 2     | 23        | 2013-01-01    | 2013-02-01    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2 | 2     | 25        | 2013-02-01    | 2013-02-05    |*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3 | 2     | 30        | 2013-02-15    | 2013-03-01    |*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4 | 2     | 27        | 2013-03-01    | NULL      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also, `NULL` means "current" so that would be `CURDATE()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: It may be simpler to create the tables in SQLFiddle, both for you and for us

Comment: Also can you give a clearer idea of the result expected, looks like its a bit unclear as to what you want to SUM()

Comment: @skv I'm looking for # of days "assigned"

Answer (score 1):

Here is the idea.  Break each record into two to get a list of dates when assignments start and stop.  Then determine how many assignments are active on a given date -- basically adding "1" for each start and "-1" for each end and taking the cumulative sum.

Next, you need to determine when the next date is to get periods before doing the final aggregation.

The first part is handled by this query:

```
select member_id, thedate,
       @sumstart := if(@prevmemberid = memberid, @sumstart + isstart, isstart) as sumstart,
       @prevmemberid := memberid
from (select member_id, start_date as thedate, 1 as isstart
      from assignments
      union all
      select member_id, end_date, -1 as isstart
      from assignments
      order by member_id, thedate
     ) a cross join
     (select @sumstart := 0, @prevmemberid := NULL) const;
```

The rest then uses more variables:

```
select member_id,
       sum(case when sumstart > 0 then datediff(nextdate, thedate) end) as daysactive
from (select member_id, thedate, sumstart,
         if(@prevmemberid = memberid, @nextdate, NULL) as nextdate,
         @prevmemberid := memberid,
         @nextdate = thedate
      from (select member_id, thedate,
                   @sumstart := if(@prevmemberid = memberid, @sumstart + isstart, isstart) as sumstart,
                   @prevmemberid := memberid
            from (select member_id, start_date as thedate, 1 as isstart
                  from assignments
                  union all
                  select member_id, coalesce(end_date, CURDATE()), -1 as isstart
                  from assignments
                  order by member_id, thedate
                 ) a cross join
                 (select @sumstart := 0, @prevmemberid := NULL) const;
           ) a cross join
           (select @nextmemberid := NULL, @nextdate := NULL) const
       order by member_id, thedate desc;
      ) a
group by member_id;
```

I don't like using variables in this way, because MySQL does not guarantee the ordering of variable assignments in a given `select`.  In practice, though, they are evaluated in the order written (which this query depends on).  Although this could be written without variables, without the `with` statement, window functions, or even views that take subqueries in the `from` clause, the resulting SQL would be *much* uglier.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to perform filter out the overlapping assignments in the code rather than in SQL.
You can retrieve all the assignments for a certain member_id, ordered by start_date:

```
select * from assignments where member_id='2' order by start_date asc
```

You can then loop over these assignments and filter out the overlapping assignments.
Two assignments A and B are non-overlapping if A ends before B starts or if B ends before A starts.

Because we ordered the results according to start date, we can safely ignore the second case: B will never start before A, so it cannot end before A starts.
We then get something like:

```
for i=0..assignments.length
    for j=i+1..assignments.length
        if (assignments[j].start_date < assignments[i].end_date)
            assignments[j] = null; // it overlaps -> get rid of it
```

Then loop over the assignments and sum the durations for the non-null assignments. This should be easy